# Можно ли экспортировать класс в DLL и использовать его?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake

Возможно подобные вопросы уже задавались, но всё же.

Можно ли экспортировать C++ класс в dll-файл и потом его использовать. Желательно без использования интерфейсов и глобальных функций, которые возвращают указатель на новый объект этого класса.

Comment: Экспортировать В DLL, или ИЗ DLL? 

Все можно, только надо учесть, что при экспорте будет непереносимость из-за разных mangled names в разных компиляторах... 

Вот [пример](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/tree/master/exper/DllClass?ref_type=heads) классов в DLL, просто объявленного как `__declspec(dllexport)`, причем в разных вариантах. Посмотрите — это то, что вас интересует?

Comment: @Harry, да это то, что я имел ввиду. Однако я не писал "__declspec(dllexport)" и "__declspec(dllimport)" обернутые в макросы, а чисто их перед именем класса. Меня заинтересовал этот метод, так как я его вижу уже не в первых раз. Например, я его видел в исходниках Unreal Engine на GitHub и других репозиториях

Comment: Мы обычно пишем макрос на каждом методе и все. Вроде в каких-то ситуациях нужно писать на всем классе, но мы не сталкивались.

Comment: Вот как это выглядит: "class APPLICATIONCORE_API FLinuxWindow : public FGenericWindow" - из репозитория Unreal Engine

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, можешь привести примеры? Меня больше интересует как потом получить методы этого класса

Comment: А что значит "как получить"? Заинклулить хедер и выставить макрос в `__declspec(dllimport)`. Вот как в вашем примере мы обычно макрос не ставим, просто перед каждым методом (кроме определенных в хедере).

Comment: и что это получается? Все методы-члены экспортируются, а сам класс что делает? Проблема еще в том, что я только недавно начал использовать dll, до этого я всегда юзал и писал статичные библиотеки.

Comment: Скорее всего вот те методы, которые вы предлагали: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840576/how-to-export-a-c-class-from-a-dll. Это они?

Comment: Не забывайте `@username`, а то уведомления не приходят.

Comment: *"а сам класс что делает"* А что должен? Мне наоборот неочевидно, что значит "экспортировать  класс", надо мануал читать. Класс - это же под капотом то же самое, что структура без методов, а то, что было методами - как свободные функции, которые принимают `this` отдельным параметром.

Comment: про @username я знаю и хотел сразу написать, но я написал их два, поэтому Stackoverflow начал ругаться что можно только одно обращение сделать, так что я решил вообще его не писать :/

Comment: @Harry, я почему-то только сейчас начал детально изучать ваш пример и хотел бы спросить. То есть, чтобы получить доступ к экспортируемому классу не нужно использовать "LoadLibrary" и "GetProcAddress"?

Comment: Если вы линкуете с соответствующей библиотекой сразу — нет, не нужно. С классами и mangled именами вы замахаетесь `GetProcAddress` вызывать...

Comment: @Harry, ок. Если имена искажаются, то как я потом могу импортировать этот класс из других файлов, не связанных с этими dll?

Comment: Ну, это будет слишком морочливо. Да и смысл? Почему не скомпилировать сразу вместе? Тем более что это все запросто может не работать, если DLL создана одним компилятором, а программа другим...

Comment: Короче, мне походу это все не подойдет. И как я понял @Harry, твой метод такой же, как и у HolyBlackCat, но немного переделанный. Я же все таки буду использовать метод с COM интерфейсами. Конечно не очень удобно писать для каждого экспортируемого класса интерфейс, но ладно. Однако, я не знаю можно ли с помощью этого метода экспортировать и использовать Singleton классы. Но скорее всего можно, так как они, в принципе, те же самые обычные классы. Спасибо за помощь. И Harry, не мог бы ты свой первый комментарий продублировать как ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Так ведь если это не годится, то что ж такой ответ писать?...

Comment: @Harry. А точно. Ладно. Спасибо за помощь!